# sending a variable to another page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am working with c# asp.net.I am trying to take an input from user and use it in another aspx page.This is my code in first page.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnProduct1Addtocart" runat="server" Text="Add to cart" postbackurl="~/CartPage.aspx"/>
```

And this is second page's code which is in codebehind.

```
Label lblProduct1Name = (Label)PreviousPage.FindControl("lblProduct1Name");
Label1.Text = lblProduct1Name.Text;
```

But i get an error like "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code" which is in the  "Label1.Text = lblProduct1Name.Text;" line.Thank you for your help.

Comment: pass value using query string of url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass the value using [query string](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString) like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnProduct1Addtocart" runat="server" Text="Add to cart" onclick="btnAddToCart_Clicked"/>
```

Code behind event:

```
private void btnAddToCart_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
Response.Redirect("~/CartPage.aspx?Name=" +lblProduct1Name.Text);
}
```

On page load of **CartPage.aspx** do like this:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["Name"];
}
```

Also have a look at this [**article**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString) to get understanding of it.

Answer (score 0):

the correct way of doing what you are trying to accomplish, is actually doing a POST to the `CartPage.aspx` page. Wrap your button with a `<form action="~/CartPage.aspx" method="POST">` and use a hidden field to hold the product id, for example:

```
<asp:HidenField ID="productID" runat="server" value="<%= Product.ID %>" />
```

Other way is to simple pass that variable in the url, like:

```
<a href="~/CartPage.aspx?productID=<%= Product.ID %>">Add to cart</a>
```

in the `CartPage.aspx` just read the `Request["productID"]` for the product id that you are passing.

*Note:* Ease on the ASP.NET Controls, it will get extremely large quickly and will slow your pages, keep as much as HTML as possible.

Comment: Nothing wrong with ASP.NET controls, so long as you selectively use ViewState only when appropriate.

Comment: @mason I'm doing WebForms since version 1.0 ... I must say, they do get in the way further and further you get better and understand HTML the way it should...

Comment: I am with @balexandre on this one. Imo, asp.net controls can break a few conventions of html markup. Mvc and razor are eel

Comment: yep @SrikanthVenugopalan since I adopted MVC (6 years ago) I can't go back to WebForms :D